Is it possible to send osquery output via syslog to a remote syslogd server on OS X?
Is it still possible to use the syslog logger plugin in osquery 5.12.1 on macOS 14.4.1 (Sonoma) to send to a remote syslog server? No matter what I do I cannot get the syslog part working.
My setup:
$ cat /var/osquery/osquery.flags
--logger_plugin=filesystem,syslog
$ cat /etc/syslog.conf 
*.*                         /var/log/system.log

Sent SIGHUP to syslogd after changing the config and restarted osquery. I do get the output in /var/log/osquery/ but nothing arrives in any /var/log/system.log.

Not directly.
Osquery's syslog logger plugin sends to the local syslog daemon. If you you want to send to a remote syslog you'd could configure the the syslog to send remotely.

Thanks, that's exactly what I've tried to do but I cannot get it working in Sonoma. That is, I cannot get the osquery output arrive in the local syslog files, which would be the first step. Are you sure that syslog is still working in Sonoma?

I think macOS syslog is all kinda weird. It may not work how you expect, and it may need additional configuration. What have you tried?

I've updated the question with what I've tried so far. Currently just trying to get the osquery output to arrive in syslog.

Is anything in /var/log/system.log? MacOS has a huge log stream. I wonder if this is landing in the unified log system.

Yes, there is some data (for example you get a log entry when you open a new tty). I cannot manage to get the standard logger command to write to the syslog though.
